# PHPUnit testing singleton

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, singleton, phpunit

I am trying to write a test for some very old code we have using PHPUnit. I've given the rough structure of it here, I am trying to test the isMember() method of ClassB which it inherits from ClassA. It should just be checking if a constant value exists in the class.

The problem I am having is that it is obviously a protected constructor, so I don't know how to test this as I keep getting protected contruct errors in PHPUnit as obviously the constructor is protected. Please advise how I test this?

```
abstract class ClassA implements InterfaceA {

    private $mValueList;
    protected static $instance;

    protected function __construct() {

    }

    protected static function getInstance(ClassA $obj) {
        if (is_null($obj->instance)) {
            $obj->instance = $obj;
        }
        return $obj->instance;       
    }

    public function isMember($value) {
        return isset($this->mValueList[$value]);
    }

    ....more methods......

}

class ClassB extends ClassA {

    public static function getInstance() {
        return parent::getInstance(new self());
    }

    const CON1 = 'string1';
    const CON2 = 'string2';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You would test it like any other class, you just don't use the constructor in the test.

```
public function testIsMember() {
    $classB = ClassB::getInstance();
    $this->assertTrue($classB->isMember('string1'));
    $this->assertFalse($classB->isMember('foo'));
}
```

I am making a guess on the assertions and you could refactor the test to use a data provider.  But the general idea is the same.  You don't invoke the constructor directly in your tests for a singleton.  The `getInstance` method replaces the call to the constructor.

Comment: I see that this is an old question but I need to raise that your answer is not right. The problem is that if you just simply test a singleton you will leak data from one test to another. What is really a dealbreaker.
So you need a method for testing purposes to be able to reset the singleton. Something like setInstance().
In the setUp() method you store the instance in the test object, an in the tearDown you set it back